Ubuntu 24.04 has issues like failed Bluetooth service and failed GNOME
Just after booting. I recently converted to Ubuntu 24.04. After using it for 1 day this happened.


Please enter your question in text form. It wil be easier for people trying to help copy/paste the errors.

@JohnCarter let's not make the OP laboriously type in all that. That screen cannot be copy/pasted, as the system does not come up. In this kind of case, the clear readable image is enough.

Looks like perhaps dBus failed to start, and the cascade occurred after that. Many possible causes. Boot a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment and review to logs of the failure. Log entries can be copied/pasted.

Should I boot a new Ubuntu system ?

Also should I strap in a new ubuntu?

@user535733 . There are free online tools that can help, though: https://www.imagetotext.info/

Here is the text after scanning it.
[ OK ] Finished plymouth-quit-wait.serviceold until boot process finishes up. [ OK ] Finished plymouth-quit.service Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen. [FAILED Failed to listen on dbus.socket - D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
ependency failed for power-profiles-daemon.service- Power Profiles daemon. IDEN dependency failed for bluetooth.service- Bluetooth service. [FAILED Failed to listen on dbus.socket D-Bus System Message Bus Socket. (DEPEND] Dependency failed for bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service. [FAILED] Failed to listen on dbus.socket

[FAILED Failed to listen on dbus.socket D-Bus System Message Bus Socket. (DEPEND] Dependency failed for bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service. [FAILED] Failed to listen on dbus.socket - D-Bus System Message Bus Socket. (DEFEND] Dependency failed for gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager.
(FAILED] Failed to start snap.cups.cups-browsed.service - Service for snap application cups.cups-browsed. [FAILED] Failed to start snap.cups.cuped.service - Service for snap application cups.cupsd.
[FAILED] Failed to start snap.remmina.ssh-agent.service - Service for snap application remmina.ssh-agent.
